# Merge 2 Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function, merge

I have the following 2 functions:

```
function undo(){
    var card = discardPile.pop();
    if( card.col != -1 ){
        sendToCol( card );
    }else{
        sendToDrawPile( card );
    }
    cardsLeft();
}

function undowaste(){
    var card = wastePile.pop();
    if( card.col != -1 ){
        sendToCol( card );
    }else{
        sendToDrawPile( card );
    }
    cardsLeft();
}
```

They are the same except for the `card value`. So I was wondering, can I merge these 2? And how to do this?

**EDIT:**
I use this function to execute both:

```
function restart(){
    if( discardPile.length){
        undo();
        setTimeout(restart,75);
    }if( wastePile.length){
        undowaste();
        setTimeout(restart,75);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function undo(pile){
    var card = pile.pop();
    if( card.col != -1 ){
        sendToCol( card );
    }else{
        sendToDrawPile( card );
    }
    cardsLeft();
}

undo(wastePile);
undo(discardPile);
```

or

```
function undo(card){
    if( card.col != -1 ){
        sendToCol( card );
    }else{
        sendToDrawPile( card );
    }
    cardsLeft();
}

undo(wastePile.pop());
undo(discardPile.pop());
```

To run at intervals

```
setInterval(function() {
  if(wastePile.length>0) undo(wastePile.pop());
  if(discardPile.length>0) undo(discardPile.pop());
},200);
```

Comment: Looks good, but I can't seem to get it working. I've added an extra function to the code. I use this function to call the other 2 functions, but it doesn't seem to work after "merging" them.